# HTML 5 datepicker showing one day before date, when sending data ajax in angular

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I am using html5 datepicker, I am sending that value via ajax using angular mysql. I have form date, in that  sending wrong if i choose 12/01, mydata saving in mysql database like 11/01/. I dont know how to solve this. I have attached my code below, thanks in advance.

HTML :

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="date1" required>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$scope.submitForm = function (){
    //console.log();
    var url = 'ajax/movies-master.php?action=add_movies';
    var d1 = {'uname': this.theatername, 'moviename': this.moviename,   'date': this.date1, 'time': this.time1, 'price': this.price };
    console.log(this.date1);
    console.log('<br/>');
    console.log(d1);
    $http.post(url, d1
    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data);
        if (data.msg != '')
        {
            $scope.msgs = data.msg;
            $scope.init();
            $scope.cancelCreating();
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.errors = data.error;
            $scope.init();
        }
    }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error  occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
        $scope.errors.push(status);
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($data->date);

$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO tablename (date) values ("' . $date . '")');
```

I am saving date like this, but my date was saving work.

Can any one know this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of your date column? Datetime, timestamp, date, etc.?

Comment: Your column name is date, right? Try using ` when you call it. Like this ``...INSERT INTO tablename (`date`) values...`` because date is a reserve word.

Answer (score 0):

Date picker always give you date which is one day before the current date ..so you need to add +1 with the date ...It will surely work for you

Comment: Thanks for your reply how to add this, for time also i facing the same problem i choosing 2PM its saving wrong in mysql database, But in javascript file if i console and check i am getting correct value. How to solve this friend